# Python HTTP server module directory location psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am attempting to use the Python HTTP server module in the directory where I have a file called login.html by running the following command: 
python -m CGIHTTPServer 8247

I am unsure of how to point this command to the correct location or if I need to do that at all. If I run it in cmd with administrative privileges I get this response:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m CGIHTTPServer 8247

Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8247 ...

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2018 12:49:36] code 404, message File not found

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2018 12:49:36] "GET /login.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2018 12:49:36] code 404, message File not found

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2018 12:49:36] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: You need to run it under the directory including `login.html`

Comment: @Sraw How do you run it under the directory?